# "c++ unit test file can be added only to Dll project type"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to test my code which is written in C++. But Visual studio show dialog box when i want to create test class for checking my code.

EDIT to clarify the question.

I have a C++ project in Visual Studio. It builds to a .EXE file.

I now want to add a unit test class.

When I try to Add New Item to the project, I can select "C++ Unit Test Class" and click Add.

But then I get a dialog box saying "C++ unit test file can be added only to Dll project type."

What is the best way to add unit tests to a project which needs to build to a .exe?

Do I need to create a new project?

Comment: There is no question here.

Answer (score 2):

The model for setting up your project with unit tests is typically:

```
Production executable -+ 
                       |--> Production code library
Unit test executable  -+
```

where the library is shared between the two, either as a statically linked lib or a DLL.

It sounds like you're trying to attach the unit tests to an exe, which may not be possible.